# Reformulate the strong induction principle as a method for proving that subsets of $\mathbb{Z}^+$ are the whole set.

Tags: induction, quantifiers

This is exercise 7.9 of *"An Introduction to Mathematical Reasoning"* by P.J.Eccles, for which the author provides a solution.

However, I've reached an alternative reformulation for the inductive step which differs from the author and I can't tell if it's correct. The problem statement goes as follows:

> Find a reformulation of the strong induction principle as a method for proving that subsets of $\mathbb{Z}^+$ are the whole set.

The author provides the following axiom for strong induction:

> Suppose that $P(n)$ is a statement involving a general positive integer $n$. Then $P(n)$ is true for all positive integers n if
>
> (i) $P(1)$ is true, and
>
> (ii) [$P(n)$ holds for all positive integers $n \le k$] $\implies$ $P(k+1)$, for all positive integers $k$.

And here is my proposed reformulation:

> Suppose that $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}^+$, the set of positive integers. Then $A=\mathbb{Z}^+$ if
>
> $\quad$(i) $1 \in A$, and
>
> $\quad$(ii) $\forall k,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+, n \le k (n \in A \implies k+1 \in A)$

As for the above reformulation, I had previously developed the following for the inductive step:

(ii) $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}^+(\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+, n \le k(n \in A \implies k+1 \in A))$

However, I found it a little ambiguous, either because of the double parenthesis, or because of the extra use of the universal statement, and that's when I came up with the reformulation I've given first.

However, the author proposes the following solution.

> Suppose that $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}^+$, the set of positive integers. Then $A=\mathbb{Z}^+$ if
>
> (i) $1 \in A$, and
>
> (ii) $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}^+((1 \le n \le k \implies n \in A) \implies k+1 \in A)$.

And as you can see, everything is the same except for the inductive step.

Hence, my question: is mine and the authors reformulation of the inductive step the same but differently stated, or have I made wrong use of the quantifiers and reached an invalid reformulation of the strong induction axiom?

Thank you!

Comment: Your's is not "parsable", in the sence that I don't know what it means $n \leq k ( n \in A \Rightarrow k+1 \in A )$. Probably you meant $n \leq k \Rightarrow ( n \in A \Rightarrow k+1 \in A )$?

Comment: If that's the case, It's much stronger than the one mentioned. Strong induction relies on the statement to hold in all smaller terms, not in at least one (which is what you require).

Comment: I thought $\forall k,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+, n \le k (n \in A \implies k+1 \in A)$ would read as "For all positive integers $k$ and $n$ such that $n$ is lesser than, or equal to $k$, if n belongs to $A$ then ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reformulation is incorrect.
$$\forall k,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+( n \le k \Rightarrow(n \in A \implies k+1 \in A))$$
(suppose you meant this) is much stronger than
$$\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}^+((1 \le n \le k \implies n \in A) \implies k+1 \in A)$$
In fact, the former proposition implies, for example, $P(1)\Rightarrow P(100)$ (take $k=100$, $n=1$). Such strong restriction is hardly suitable for a reformulation of induction principle.

Comment: Thank you. I thought my statement was incorrect but still logically valid, or as @PenasRaul said, "parsable".